# How to click on the second link with the same text using Capybara in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, capybara

In a view file I have:

```
= link_to 'View', post
= link_to 'View', comment
```

In a spec file (I'm using Capybara):

```
click_on 'View'
```

It clicks on the first link, but I want it to click on the second one. How can I do it?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

There's probably a few ways but I usually scope something like this.

```
within(".comment") do
  click_on("View")
end
```

There's quite possibly/probably alternatives as well.  I usually do my acceptance testing from cucumber, so my steps typically look like

```
When I follow "View" within the comment element
```

Where I have a step that translates `within the comment element` to a scoped call to the step itself (which I think is built into the latest capybara web_steps)

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no css-class "comment". Two links are identical. The only difference between them is their positions. One goes after another. I want to click on the second link.

Comment: I'd submit that you should then introduce either a class on the link you want to select or a wrapper element as a hook for testing. You may be able to use the nth-child pseudoselector (http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-child-pseudo) but I recommend against it as it introduces a brittle and order-dependent linkage into your tests.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I needed! In my case 'nth-child' is great!

Answer (score 67):

You could try to find all entries and deal with an array:

```
page.all('a')[1].click
```

Would help to have a class or use *within* to scope your search ;)

Comment: Works if you have only two links on your page :)

Comment: Should work regardless of number as long as you know the order the links appears on the page. Could easily call

``page.all('a')[2].click``

Answer (score 18):

The worst thing about "the second" link is that it can become the third or the first or even the twenty fifth someday. So, scoping with a `within` block is the best way. Example:

```
within(".comment") do
  click_on("View")
end
```

But if it is difficult to specify the link with a `within` scope (which sometimes it really is), I guess the way to click the second link with a certain text is:

```
 find(:xpath, "(//a[text()='View'])[2]").click
```

In later versions of capybara (`2.0.2`, for example) both **click_on 'View'** and **click_link 'View'** will raise an ambiguous match error:

```
 Failure/Error: click_on 'View'
 Capybara::Ambiguous:
   Ambiguous match, found 2 elements matching link or button "View"
```

So this won't do even if you want to click the first link (or if any link would be ok, which is my case).

As far as I understand this is made to force people write more specific tests where particular links are clicked.

It definitely could be tricky to debug the code if you accidentally placed two or more links with identical text and try to see what is happening. It's good to rely on something that is unlikely to change and specifying a link with a `within` block is a nice way to do this.

Answer (score 17):

There are many ways for solving this type of problems.

Do it like this

```
if(page.find("a")[:href] == "comment")
    click_on("View")
```

or

```
page.find("a:eq(2)").click
```

---

**Remember javascript indexing starts with 0 while In Capybara, indexing starts with 1**. So use a:eq(2) here for second href.

Comment: just note that's not "capybara indexing", it's just how CSS selectors work

Answer (score 8):

For `capybara 2` solution:

```
within(".comment") do
  click_on("View")
end
```

would not help if you have a few `.comment`. So simple use: `page.first(:link, "View").click`

Comment: The second link is what the author wants here.

Answer (score 4):

This works for me if you have several rows of identical classes and you want to find the second row. Like a previous author mentioned, capybara indexing starts at 1.

```
within all(".trip-row")[2] do
   assert page.has_content?("content")
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use [capybara-ui](https://github.com/mojotech/capybara-ui) you could define the widget, or reusable DOM reference, for each widget.

```
# define your widget. in this case,
# we're defining it in a role
widget :view_post, ['.post', text: 'View']
widget :view_comment, ['.comment', text: 'View']

# then click that widget in the test
role.click :view_post
role.click :view_comment
```