# destroy test in rails with minitest capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, minitest

I'm trying to get the syntax just right. I think I'm close but I'm trying to make a test to show that my admin can destroy a user. The error I get right now is :

```
Ambiguous match, found 2 elements matching link or button "delete
```

and I totally understand that. That means I get to the users index page and I see the delete button for a regular user and the admin. How do I exactly specify which user I want to click the delete button on so I can delete them in the test.

here is my users.yml file

```
user:
  name: user
  email: user@examle.com
  admin: false
  password_digest: <%= BCrypt::Password.create('password') %>

admin:
  name: admin
  email: admin@admin.com
  admin: true
  password_digest: <%= BCrypt::Password.create('password') %>
```

here is my admin_test.rb file

```
require "test_helper"

feature "as a blog owner I want a working user delete so I can remove trolls" do
  scenario 'admin can delete profile' do
    visit new_session_path
    fill_in 'Email', with: users(:admin).email
    fill_in 'password', with: 'password'
    click_on 'Log In'
    visit users_path(:admin)
    click_on 'delete'
    click_on 'OK'
    page.must_have_content "User deleted"
  end
end
```

I think the problem is caused on the line

```
click_on 'delete'
```

anyone know what the right syntax is or what I'm messing up?

Comment: Check this [SO Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6733427/how-to-click-on-the-second-link-with-the-same-text-using-capybara-in-rails-3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First issue is that you probably don't want to be able to delete an admin.  You also don't want to delete yourself.  I would suggest adding an admin? boolean method to test for whether a user is an admin or not so that it doesn't show the delete option for admins.  Something like this in your view would work then:

```
<% if current_user.admin? && !current_user?(user) %>
    | <%= link_to "delete", user, method: :delete,
                                  data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
<% end %>
```

Second is the issue when have two of the same element and get an ambiguous match.  For testing a lot of times you only want to select one out of the many.  You could just select the first one:

```
first('.item').click_link('Agree')
```

You can check out this answer for more info: [How to click first link in list of items after upgrading to Capybara 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14513377/how-to-click-first-link-in-list-of-items-after-upgrading-to-capybara-2-0)