# how to click one item in list of items with capybara

Tags: ruby, testing, capybara

My html Code i have a button

```
<input class="search hidden" id="search_button" type="submit" value="Search" style="display: block;"></input>
```

when i clicked in Button many items is generated like this :

```
<div id="search_results" class="" style="display: block; left: 522.083px; top: 459.617px; width: 398px;"> 
    <img alt="Load-circle" class="load-circle" src=".../123">
    <div id="app_341446764" class="search-result"><img src=".../DictationIcon.png">abc</div>
    <div id="app_561941526" class="search-result"><img src=".../Icon.png">def</div>
</div>
```

i have many div with class search-result i don't know how to click one of them(class="search-result") anyone suggest me a solution.

Comment: Why don't you add an index to the generated div id? like.. id = "searh_results_#{index}", that way you know what div do you want to click

Comment: that not my code i can't change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you would add a unique id as @juan-manuel-rodulfo-salcedo suggested. However, if you can't do that then you could find all the divs with `class=search-result`. Below is an example of how to click the second div on the page:

```
page.all('.search-result')[1].click
```

For more examples of how to select multiple elements, see this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6733427/how-to-click-on-the-second-link-with-the-same-text-using-capybara-in-rails-3).